# Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

> Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.....

**Action file:**

```
import $ from 'jquery'

import { phoneVerify } from '../actions/types'

const verifyPhoneAsync = function (verification) {
  return {
    type: phoneVerify,
    payload: verification
  }
}
const verifyPhone = function (phone) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'api',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { mobile: phone },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    }
  })
}
const verifyOtp = function (phone, otp) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'api',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { mobile: phone, code: otp, devicetoken: 'nil', devicetype: 'nil' },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: (data) => {
        if (data.success === true) {
          localStorage.setItem('MobileNumber', phone)
          const varification = data
          dispatch(verifyPhoneAsync(varification))
        } else {
          console.log('rfg')
          const varification = data
          dispatch(verifyPhoneAsync(varification))
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
export { verifyPhone, verifyOtp }
```

Comment: You should share your redux actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot return in action verifyPhone, so you got this error.

Answer (score 2):

Your store is not configured with the redux-thunk middleware. Therefore your store doesn't know how to dispatch actions which are functions.

> Middleware is not baked into createStore and is not a fundamental part
>   of the Redux architecture

Since you have not added any middleware you can only dispatch actions which are objects.

Firstly, you do not need [compose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41359312/3946931) when you only have one store enhancer.

**Compose is used when we want to apply multiple store enhancers to our store.**

**applyMiddleware is a store enhancer for adding middleware to our dispatch chain.**

Note that applyMiddleware and the only store enhancer built into redux

**Store enhancers: extends store itself**

Store enhancers are just higher order functions that give us new store creators with extended functionality.

**Middleware: extends dispatch method of store**

Whereas middleware are higher order functions that return a new dispatch method on our redux store that will run some custom logic when a new action is dispatched.

**How to set up a redux store with middleware such as redux-thunk**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'

let middleware = [ thunk ] // add additional middleware to this array

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  preloadedState,
  applyMiddleware(...middleware)
)
```

So your code will look like this:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import AppContainer from './views/App/container'
import './index.scss'
import reducer from './store/reducers'

let middleware = [ thunk ]

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
   applyMiddleware(...middleware)
)

ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}>
       <Router history={ browserHistory }>
         <Route path="/" component={ AppContainer }/>
       </Router>
   </Provider>,
   document.getElementById('root')
)
```

See the docs for the complete [applyMiddleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html) api

Answer (score 0):

You have got this error because you are using an ajax call (asynchronous call) directly in your `action`,

that is because Actions are meant to be plain JavaScript objects and must have a type property that indicates the type of action being performed.

Consider using `redux-thunk` middleware for `api call` purposes to avoid this issue.

For more information:

[Redux Async Actions](https://h3manth.com/new/blog/2018/redux-async-actions/)

[Redux Thunk](https://medium.com/@stowball/a-dummys-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react-d8904a7005d3)