# Please explain how the compose function in redux works

Tags: javascript, redux, function-composition

The [`compose` function](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/src/compose.js) in Redux is really simple for the most part and I understand how to use it.

```
export default function compose(...funcs) {
  if (funcs.length === 0) {
    return arg => arg
  }

  if (funcs.length === 1) {
    return funcs[0]
  }

  return funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => a(b(...args)))
}
```

However, this one part of the last bit seems really obscure to me:

```
funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => a(b(...args)))
```

What is the `...args` part? I understand these are rest parameters but what is it evaluating to? Where is it coming from?

Comment: [`...` is not an operator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196). You can read about [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and ["call spread"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) on MDN. *"what is it evaluating to"* They are both syntactic constructs with different meanings. The first one means that all arguments are collected in an array accessible via `args`. The second one means to pass all entries of (the iterable referenced by) `args` as arguments to `b`.

Comment: awesome  - good catch - will read this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding compose functions in redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357897/understanding-compose-functions-in-redux)

Answer (score 1):

Compose is just allowing you to write

```
compose(func1, func2, func3, func4)
```

instead of

```
func1(func2(func3(func4))))
```

In case of

```
funcs.reduce((a, b) => (...args) => a(b(...args)))
```

.reduce is a function of array, you can read about [Array Reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

It is returning

```
(...args) => a(b(...args);
```

and giving you an option to pass some parameters to the nested functions.

for example:
It is allowing you to write something like this:

```
 nestedFunc = compose(func1, func2, func3);

 nestedFunc({key: value})
```

which will result in

```
func1(func2(func3({key: value})))
```

[Read more about compose function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357897/understanding-compose-functions-in-redux)